# RSpec in Sinatra always running in development

Tags: rspec, sinatra

I'm trying to get RSpec to run in a simple Sinatra app, but every time I run my test suite, it runs in development mode instead of test mode.

Based on what I've read, my `spec_helper` is correct, but it's still always using the development environment.

spec/spec_helper.rb

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb
ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'

require File.expand_path './../../app.rb', __FILE__
require 'rack/test'
require 'rspec'

module RSpecMixin
  include Rack::Test::Methods
  def app; App; end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include RSpecMixin
end
```

What am I missing?

Comment: How do you check that Sinatra is, in fact, running in `development`? I mean, for example, dev and test envs can be configured with the same DB, and if one checked DB contents one could think it's a dev env.

Comment: In each test, I'm doing a `puts settings.environment` and its returning `development`. There is no database connected to this application.

Comment: What is the value of `ENV['RACK_ENV']` immediately after the line `require File.expand_path`... in the spec_helper?

Comment: `puts ENV['RACK_ENV'].inspect` -> `"test"`

Comment: I'd replace the `App` with an anonymous app and see if that changes anything e.g. change `def app; App; end` to `def app; Sinatra.new { get("/") { settings.environment } }; end` and set up a simple spec for it and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

According to this doc: http://sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#environment---configurationdeployment-environment

The value defaults to `:development` when there's no RACK_ENV set. I'm guessing that app (and config) is already initialized do `ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'` in `spec/spec_helper.rb`.

You can check if `require File.expand_path './../../app.rb', __FILE__` returns true.

Comment: Right. That's exactly what I'm doing above. And I know the `require` works because if I change that line at all, the tests fail because the app isn't loaded.